# residuals with non-zero mean

Tags: time-series, forecasting, white-noise

Once you learned your forecasting model, it is necessary to check if the residuals are a white noise: the mean is zero and no autorrelation. If the residuals have mean m, the rule is to add m to all forecasts and the bias problem is solved. Can someone explain to me this rule?

Thanks

Comment: After you add $m$ to all forecasts, what is the mean of the new residuals?

Comment: @whuber $m$ too ?

Comment: The residual, by definition, is the difference between an observed value and its fitted value.  When you increase the fitted value by $m,$ what happens to the difference?

Comment: @whuber the difference either get increased or decreased by $m$ based on the sign of $m$. We get:  observed value - fitted value - $m$. I guess there is a mistake in here: https://otexts.com/fpp2/residuals.html. We should substract the mean and not add it to the forecasts.

Comment: That comment seems to be confused about subtraction.  Work out an example.  For instance, if a value is $2$ and the fitted value is $3,$ the residual is $2-3 = -1$.  If you then add $m=-1$ to the fitted value, you get a new fit of $3 + -1 = 2$ and the new residual is $2 - 2 = 0.$  That the same thing as subtracting $m$ from the original residual, because $-1 - m = -1 - (-1) = 0.$